# how to make laravel echo setup js on cdn

Tags: laravel, sockets, redis

I am using Laravel echo server with redis, a socket notfication. I used this tutorial:

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-broadcast-redis-socket-io-tutorial-example.html

There a JS file is created, "laravel-echo-setup.js." Is there is a way to read this file from cdnjs instead locally?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<script src="{{ url('/js/laravel-echo-setup.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

By:

```
<script src="https://{HERE YOUR REMOTE URL}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```